# Is it possible to deploy a Flutter application to IOS/Apple Store without an Iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, provisioning-profile, iosdeployment

When I run `flutter build ios`:

```
myair:myapp me$ flutter build ios
Building com.myapp.app for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified 
development team in Xcode project:
XXXXXXXXXX
Running pod install...                                       3.4s
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            2.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "My Prov Profile" doesn't include signing
certificate "iPhone Distribution: Me (XXXXXXXXXX)".
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.1'
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.1'
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.1'

Encountered error while building for device.
myair:myapp me$
```

So that said I have a provisioning profile but i do not own an Iphone to add to the profile.

I tried using a UDID from a simulator, but it did not accept it as a real UDID.

I'd like to push my Flutter app to ios device testers through testflight before releasing this to the public.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
I'm still stuck. I believe in the past (xcode <= 8.*) i was able to build an archive and manually upload it to itunes connect with out an actual device on the profile. This doesn't seem possible in xcode 10.

Comment: Check https://codemagic.io/ you can release your app

Comment: I seem to be having a lot of issues with it. It chokes up when building dependencies, and it still seems like i need a provisioning profile that'll sign iphone targets.